# How would I host an external application in WPF?

Tags: wpf, hosting, external

How can I host a (`.Net, Java, VB6, MFC, etc`) application in a `WPF window` ?.

I have a need to use `WPF windows` to wrap external applications and control the window size and location.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this or a direction to research in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a HwndHost to host the outside window in your application.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://www.ddj.com/windows/197003872?pgno=2) explains how to use HwndHost along with a few other Win32 API calls to accomplish the task.